# Android MMS Content Provider does not store Transaction IDs

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, pdu, android-mms

I'm developing an app that has a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for the [WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED_ACTION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents#WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED_ACTION) and then attempts to download the content of the MMS using [downloadMultimediaMessage()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#downloadMultimediaMessage(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

However, this only works if the default messaging app (which is not mine) doesn't get to it first, since once the MMS is downloaded, the carrier usually deletes the MMS from its servers.

When this happens, I have to fallback to finding the downloaded MMS in Android's MMS Content Provider. The only reliable piece of information I have to find the MMS I'm looking for, is the Transaction ID I obtained from the [WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED_ACTION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents#WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED_ACTION) notification, but for some reason, all [Transaction IDs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.BaseMmsColumns#TRANSACTION_ID) in the content provider are `null`.

How can I reliably find the MMS in the content provider using only the information I receive in my `BroadcastReceiver`?